# How to Dispose myClass with Garbage Collecter C#

Tags: c#

I have a class and got a method that doin so many things in memory and need to be disposed when its jobs done.But i have looked for MSDN for solution.There is an example thats not solved my problem.When my Class is instanced and run this method my memory is getting bigger and bigger.How can i Dispose it when its job done ? 
Here is my CODES ;

```
class Deneme
{
    public Deneme()
    { }
    ~Deneme()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    public void TestMetodu()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
       // This is my method that doing big jobs :)
    }



}

 Deneme CCCX = new Deneme();
        CCCX.TestMetodu();
        CCCX = null;
```

So i cant dispose it with this.

Comment: Did you tried this İbrahim? http://www.csharpnedir.com/articles/read/?id=558

Comment: Why the down vote to this question?

Comment: You should look at what you're doing in your code. In theory, all managed code should have its memory managed effectively by the CLR, it is usually a bad idea to mess about with that. Is your code using any external resources and not freeing them up? (sockets, file handles, database connections etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
~Deneme()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

You don't need to use `GC.Collect()` or `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`, because at this point, the garbage collector is already collecting the object.

You want to use the `Dispose` method, so you can encapsulate the object use in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx) statement.  Here is a link that will show you the pattern on how to implement it:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Ashish1/dispose02152006095441AM/dispose.aspx

link to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx

```
            private bool IsDisposed
            {
                get;set;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                 Dispose(true);
                 GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            ~CLASS_NAME()
            {
                 Dispose(false);
            }

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposedStatus)
            {
                if (!IsDisposed)
                {
                     IsDisposed = true;

                     // Released unmanaged Resources
                     if (disposedStatus)
                     {
                      // Released managed Resources
                     }
                 }
            }
```

Comment: I think it should be brought up that setting an object to `null` does not tell the CLR to garbage collect the instance right then and there. Moreover, you are only guaranteed that finalizers run "eventually". Once you take these two points into consideration, implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 4):

implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) (with function Dispose) and then wrap the creation of your object in a using statement. (when the object goes out of scope (after the using block), the dispose will be called.)

Furthermore, [never call GC.Collect().](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx)

Comment: The `Dispose` method is different from `Finalize` - he shouldn't be including a `~Deneme()` method.

Comment: A nitpick: the GC is completely unaware of, and will never call, the `Dispose` method.

Comment: @luke: fixed, happens when the object goes out of scope

Answer (score 4):

Does your class directly use any unmanaged resources, or hold references to any [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) objects? If so, then you should probably implement `IDisposable` to clean-up those resources, and then wrap all uses of your class in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.

If your class only uses managed resources, and doesn't hold references to any `IDisposable` objects, then you should probably let the GC do its job without any interference. Just ensure that the lifetime of any instances of your class are kept as short as possible.

Comment: +1 Dispose is *only* useful for unmanaged resources.  Using it with a purely managed set of objects will have no effect.

Comment: @Paolo: What!? `Dispose()` is useful in anyplace `finally` is, which definitely happens in managed code

Comment: @BlueRaja - Paolo is saying that you should only be releasing unmanaged resources inside of the `Dispose()` method, not that you should never call it from managed code

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a few issues here and you need to look into this in a little more detail, the .net garbage collector usually does a pretty good job on its own and needs verly litle help from the developer.

1. Use the Dispose interface if you
   really really need to (usually this
   is to release any unmanaged
   resources you may have used)
2. dont call gc.collect(), you can
   really mess up the garbage
   collection cycle
3. in you code use the using statement
   on any objects that impliment
   idisposable to ensure they are made
   available for collection as soon as
   possible.

To me it seems you need to look at the "big jobs" as it seems there may be a memory leak there, proper coding of that would probably alleviate the need to do any cleaning up afterwards.

[here](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae) is a good read on GC

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't quite understand your example. If you hold unmanaged resources (like File handles etc.) you want to implement `IDisposable` and override the member it provides, `Dispose`.

There is a recommended pattern when using `IDisposable` which you can read about at the [.NET docs for IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

However this is not a guarantee that your object will be collected when you call Dispose, only that the resources it uses is freed (as long as you've implemented your class correctly of course.) As the documentation states:

> The primary use of this interface is
>   to release unmanaged resources. The
>   garbage collector automatically
>   releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no
>   longer used. However, it is not
>   possible to predict when garbage
>   collection will occur. Furthermore,
>   the garbage collector has no knowledge
>   of unmanaged resources such as window
>   handles, or open files and streams.
>
> Use the Dispose method of this
>   interface to explicitly release
>   unmanaged resources in conjunction
>   with the garbage collector. The
>   consumer of an object can call this
>   method when the object is no longer
>   needed.

IDisposable is only there for freeing unmanaged resources, your class however is managed. It is under the control of the garbage collector.

What I think you are asking for is managing the lifetime of the managed object (your class), which is as far as I know not recommended unless there is a really really strong reason to. I don't exactly have the most exotic needs but I've never had to do this myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for an application to use more and more memory (up to a certain point) until the memory is needed for something else. There is no reason for the application to waste time with cleaning up unused objects if the memory isn't needed, the computer doesn't run any faster from having a lot of unused memory.

If the application continues to grow uncontrollably, then you have a problem. If the memory goes back down after a while, it's not a problem. You can test to minimise the program, that normally causes it to return as much memory to the system as possible.

If you are using objects in your method that implements IDisposable you should make sure that they are disposed properly. Otherwise they can't be cleaned up until the garbage collector has first called the Finalize method on each of them. There is a background thread that runs Finalize calls one at a time, so if you leave a lot of objects undisposed, it can take a while until they are all processed and ready to be cleaned up by garbage collection.